# Rails 4 Polymorphic associations and concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to add an `Evaluation` model to my `Rails 4` app.

I have made a model called `evaluation.rb`. It has:

```
class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :evaluator, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :evaluatable, :polymorphic => true
```

I have also made concerns for `evaluator` and `evaluatable` as:

```
module Evaluator
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do 
        has_many :given_evaluations, as: :evaluator, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Evaluation'

    end
end

module Evaluatable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do 
        has_many :received_evaluations, as: :evaluatable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Evaluation'
    end
end
```

I have included each concern in my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Evaluator
   include Evaluatable
```

In my show page, I want to show a particular user's evaluations (received from other users -who are evaluators).

In my show, I have:

```
<% Evaluation.find(params[:id]).evaluations.order('created_at DESC').each do |eval| %>
                                <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
                                        <%= eval.remark %>
                                        <%= eval.personal_score %>
                                        <small><%= eval.created_at %></small>
```

In my evaluations form, I"m not sure how to designate the recipient of the evaluation. I have made the basic form, but I'm not clear about how to tie it to the user who should receive the evaluation.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@evaluation) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :score, collection: 1..10, autofocus: true, :label => "How do you rate this experience (1 being did not meet expectations - 10 being met all expectations) ?" %>

    <%= f.input :remark, as: :text, :label => "Evaluate your project experience", :input_html => {:rows => 10}  %>
```

My evaluations table has:

```
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "evaluatable_id"
    t.string   "evaluatable_type"
    t.integer  "overall_score"
    t.integer  "project_score"
    t.integer  "personal_score"
    t.text     "remark"
    t.boolean  "work_again?"
    t.boolean  "continue_project?"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  end

  add_index "evaluations", ["evaluatable_type", "evaluatable_id"], name: "index_evaluations_on_evaluatable_type_and_evaluatable_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

**QUESTIONS**

How do I setup the show page to show a user's evaluations received?

How do I adapt the form so that it specifies a user id as the person who should receive the evaluation?

Comment: Great question and you are good at explaining your problems.. lets see if any one helps

Comment: Do you intend to use `Evaluation` for evaluating objects other than users? Base on your reply, answer can be simplified.

Comment: Yes. i want to evaluate projects that users do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How do I setup the show page to show a user's evaluations received?**

Your model concerns should help you with that. In your `UsersController#show` action, simply adding the following should do the trick:

```
@received_evaluations = @user.received_evaluations
```

Then you can use it in your show template:

```
<% @received_evaluations.each do |evaluation| %>
  // render some view stuff
<% end %>
```

Or use [collection rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections).

*note: the `Evaluation.find(...)` that's currently in your view should be put in the controller action, it's not good practice to leave that in the view.*

**How do I adapt the form so that it specifies a user id as the person who should receive the evaluation?**

If you have identified the user that will serve as `evaluatable` you could set it in your controller action or in your view form in case you have a list of users to evaluate on your page.

In the controller:

```
@evaluation.evaluatable_id = user_to_evaluate.id
@evaluation.evaluatable_type = user_to_evaluate.class.to_s
```

Or this simpler statement should do the same:

```
@evaluation.evaluatable = user_to_evaluate
```

Similarly, you should be able to set the evaluator the same way:

```
@evaluation.evaluator = user_that_evaluates
```

In the view:

```
<% @users_to_evaluate.each do |user| %>
  <%= simple_form_for(Evaluation.new) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :score, collection: 1..10, autofocus: true, :label => "How do you rate this experience (1 being did not meet expectations - 10 being met all expectations) ?" %>
      <%= f.input :remark, as: :text, :label => "Evaluate your project experience", :input_html => {:rows => 10}  %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :evaluator_id, :value => current_user.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :evaluator_type, :value => current_user.class.to_s %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :evaluatable_id, :value => user.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :evaluatable_type, :value => user.class.to_s %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: alright!! Thanks very much Marc. I'll give it a try tonight.