# Rails 4 - post completion evaluations model - structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I'm still feeling my way with Rails.

I'm trying to add an evaluation function to my projects based app.

I want each project participant to submit an evaluation when a project is complete.

I have an evaluation model with:

Evaluation.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: evaluations
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id           :integer
#  evaluatable_id    :integer
#  evaluatable_type  :string
#  overall_score     :integer
#  project_score     :integer
#  personal_score    :integer
#  remark            :text
#  work_again?       :boolean
#  continue_project? :boolean
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_evaluations_on_evaluatable_type_and_evaluatable_id  (evaluatable_type,evaluatable_id) UNIQUE
#

class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base

  # --------------- associations

  belongs_to :evaluator, :polymorphic => true, class_name: 'Evaluation'
  belongs_to :evaluatable, :polymorphic => true, class_name: 'Evaluation'


  # --------------- scopes

  # --------------- validations

  # --------------- class methods

  # --------------- callbacks

  # --------------- instance methods

  # --------------- private methods

end
```

I have concerns for:

```
module Evaluatable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do 
        has_many :received_evaluations, as: :evaluatable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Evaluation'
    end
end

module Evaluator
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do 
        has_many :given_evaluations, as: :evaluator, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Evaluation'

    end
end
```

I'm then trying to show each user's evaluations (received) as:

```
<% Evaluation.find(params[:id]).evaluation.order('created_at DESC').each do |eval| %>
                                <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
                                        <%= eval.remark %>
                                        <%= eval.personal_score %>
                                        <small><%= eval.created_at %></small>
                                </div>    
                            <% end %>
```

But I get this error:

```
undefined method `evaluations' for #<Evaluation:0x007ff274b13b90>
Did you mean?  evaluator
               evaluator=
```

I'm not even sure I've understood the error message, let alone figured out what to do about it.

Can anyone make sense of this message?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your relations

```
:polymorphic => true,
```

Here is a article when we should use polymorphics relations.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: But why? I want each party to a project to evaluate the other project participants

Comment: This is what I'm trying to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394489/rails-4-polymorphic-associations-and-concerns