# Evaluation - polymorphic associations on feedback loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to figure out how to implement an evaluation model in my Rails 4 app.

I've previously asked these related questions but am yet to solve this problem:

[Rails 4 Polymorphic associations and concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394489/rails-4-polymorphic-associations-and-concerns)

[Rails 4 - post completion evaluations model - structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497137/rails-4-post-completion-evaluations-model-structure)

I have:

```
class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :evaluator, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :evaluatable, :polymorphic => true
```

I have also made concerns for evaluator and evaluatable as:

```
module Evaluator
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do 
        has_many :given_evaluations, as: :evaluator, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Evaluation'

    end
end
module Evaluatable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do 
        has_many :received_evaluations, as: :evaluatable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Evaluation'
    end
end
```

I have included each concern in my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Evaluator
   include Evaluatable
```

In my show page, I want to show a particular user's evaluations (received from other users -who are evaluators).

In my show, I have:

```
<% Evaluation.find(params[:id]).received_evaluations.order('created_at DESC').each do |eval| %>
                                <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
                                        <%= eval.remark %>
                                        <%= eval.personal_score %>
                                        <small><%= eval.created_at %></small>
```

In my evaluations form, I"m not sure how to designate the recipient of the evaluation. I have made the basic form, but I'm not clear about how to tie it to the user who should receive the evaluation.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@evaluation) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :score, collection: 1..10, autofocus: true, :label => "How do you rate this experience (1 being did not meet expectations - 10 being met all expectations) ?" %>

    <%= f.input :remark, as: :text, :label => "Evaluate your project experience", :input_html => {:rows => 10}  %>
```

My evaluations table has:

```
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "evaluatable_id"
    t.string   "evaluatable_type"
    t.integer  "overall_score"
    t.integer  "project_score"
    t.integer  "personal_score"
    t.text     "remark"
    t.boolean  "work_again?"
    t.boolean  "continue_project?"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  end

  add_index "evaluations", ["evaluatable_type", "evaluatable_id"], name: "index_evaluations_on_evaluatable_type_and_evaluatable_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

In my users controller, I have:

```
def show
    # authorize! :read, @user
    @received_evaluations = @user.received_evaluations
  end
```

I currently get an error that says:

```
undefined method `received_evaluations' for #<Evaluation:0x007fb8c4b32160>
```

I'm not sure what this message means or how to solve it.

If I change the show to:

```
<% @user.received_evaluations.each do |eval| %>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `received_evaluations' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your different questions on this issue I think what are are trying to set up a mechanism for one `User` to evaluate another `User`.

Based on the above logic, the use of polymorphic associations is not required.  They are probably overcomplicating things for you.

This is what I think you need:

```
class User
  has_many :given_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, class_name: Evaluation
  has_many :received_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, class_name: Evaluation
end

class Evaluation
  belongs_to :evaluator, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, class_name: User
  belongs_to :evaluatee, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, class_name: User
end
```

Your evaluation table would be like this:

```
id                :integer          not null, primary key
evaluator_id      :integer          not null
evaluatee_id      :integer          not null
overall_score     :integer
continue_project  :boolean
created_at        :datetime         not null
updated_at        :datetime         not null
```

You can then do away with the `Evaluator` and `Evaluatable` modules.

So, now to display a user's received evaluations and get rid of the error messages you are receiving:

In the controller:

```
# ensure we get the user for all relevant routes
before_filter :get_user, only: [:show, edit, :update, :destroy]

def get_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def show
  # get the received evaluations and order
  @received_evaluations = @user.received_evaluations
  @received_evaluations = @received_evaluations.order('created_at DESC')

  # you will probably want grab the evaluator record as well...
  @received_evaluations = @received_evaluations.includes(:evaluator)
end
```

And in the **show** view

```
<% @received_evaluations.each do |eval| %>
  <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
    <%= eval.remark %>
    <%= eval.personal_score %>
    <small><%= eval.created_at %></small>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When I try this, I create a new evaluation and get an error that says: Couldn't find User with 'id'=3. Each time  I make a new one, the number increments by 1. I don't think these are user ids, rather they are evaluation ids. I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: the above actions are in the evaluations controller. Do I need to add something to the users controller to get this to work?