# Rails - Feedback loop models - user as "evaluator" and "evalutable"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I'm getting confused with my attempts to implement a feedback loop in my Rails 4 app.

I have asked questions relating to this problem here:

[Evaluation - polymorphic associations on feedback loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506781/evaluation-polymorphic-associations-on-feedback-loop)

I'm still trying to figure out the general approach - and the solution to those questions, but I am having a specific issue is about how to setup the model in relation to its association with user.

I'm trying to destroy all users in my rails console, however I'm getting stopped with an error that says:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column evaluations.evaluator_id does not exist
```

I think that means that I need to put an 'evaluator_id' column in my evaluations table.

Currently, that table has:

```
id                :integer          not null, primary key
  user_id           :integer
  evaluatable_id    :integer
  evaluatable_type  :string
  overall_score     :integer
  continue_project? :boolean
  created_at        :datetime         not null
  updated_at        :datetime         not null

 Indexes

  index_evaluations_on_evaluatable_type_and_evaluatable_id  (evaluatable_type,evaluatable_id) UNIQUE
```

In each case, evaluator is an alias for user. User is also the owner of the evaluation. I'm not sure whether I do actually need to add the evaluator_id to user, since I already have user on my model.

Can anyone see what I'm supposed to do to fix this problem?

Comment: What table/model is the one you provide here?

Answer (score 0):

Your Evaluation model both belongs to Evaluator and Evaluatable as per other post. But your table seems to have no foreign key for Evaluator... you should create a migration making 'reference' to Evaluator

Answer (score 0):

Reading your different questions on this issue I think you are trying to set up a mechanism for one `User` to evaluate another `User`.

Based on the above logic, the use of polymorphic associations is not required.  They are probably overcomplicating things for you.

This is what I think would suite your requirements better:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :given_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Evaluation
  has_many :received_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Evaluation
end

class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :evaluator, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, class_name: User
  belongs_to :evaluatee, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, class_name: User
end
```

Your evaluation table would be like this:

```
id                :integer          not null, primary key
evaluator_id      :integer          not null
evaluatee_id      :integer          not null
overall_score     :integer
continue_project  :boolean
created_at        :datetime         not null
updated_at        :datetime         not null
```

You can then do away with the `Evaluator` and `Evaluatable` modules.

Given an `Evaluation`, you can access the `User` that performed and received the evaluation like so:

```
evaluation = Evaluation.first
evaluator = evaluation.evaluator # returns a User
evaluatee = evaluation.evaluatee # returns a User
```

And you can access a users given and received evaluations with the following:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
given_evaluations = user.given_evaluations
received_evaluations = user.received_evaluations
```

---

Alternatively, if you really want to separate out the functionality of an `Evaluator` and `Evaluatee` you can create separate classes that both access the same `users` table.  This is more of a Single Table Inheritance structure.

```
class User
end

class Evaluator < User
  has_many :evaluations
end

class Evaluatee < User
  has_many :evaluations
end

class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :evaluator
  belongs_to :evaluatee
end
```

Given an `Evaluation`, you can access the the users like so:

```
evaluation = Evaluation.first
evaluator = evaluation.evaluator # returns a Evaluator
evaluatee = evaluation.evaluatee # returns a Evaluatee
```

And you can access a users given and received evaluations with the following:

```
user_id = params[:id]
given_evaluations = Evaluator.find(user_id).evaluations
received_evaluations = Evaluatee.find(user_id).evaluations

# or

given_evaluations = Evaluation.where(evaluator_id: user_id)
received_evaluations = Evaluation.where(evaluatee_id: user_id)
```

The caveat of this approach is that dependent destruction of evaluation records becomes a little more difficult as the associations as split over two separate models.

Comment: Hi Brent, I think I tried the approach the way I have is because I want students to participate in group projects and then to leave feedback for each other. The evaluation belongs to the project as well as the users. Does your suggested approach mean that I can't assign the feedback to the project as well as the users?

Comment: Just to confirm, can you clarify what a student is evaluating?  Are they giving feedback for the project itself, or feedback to individual members of the project, or both?

Comment: Both the other student and the project. For project, they answer questions like 'continue_project?' if they want to keep working on it. Most of the questions are feedback for the other participants

Comment: Okay, then just focus on the `given_evaluations` relationship on the `User` model and the `evaluator` association on the `Evaluation` model.  The additional options to define the `foreign_key` and the `class_name` are required to fix the specific error you are getting as I have done in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm trying it now.

Comment: I tried the first alternative, but I get undefined method `received_evaluations' for nil:NilClass
error message

Comment: I've tried adding     @received_evaluations = user.received_evaluations
 to the show action of each the evaluations controller and the users controller, but in each case I get an error that says: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<EvaluationsController:0x007fd92bbecfd8>
I've tried switching user for current_user but that doesnt work either. i'm stuck

Comment: What about `@user`??

Comment: tried it too = undefined method `received_evaluations' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113358/discussion-between-br3nt-and-mel).