# Rails - feedback on specific users, how to set up the form to identify relevant users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I've been trying, for the last few months, to figure out how to set up an evaluation model so that some users can evaluate other users on their joint projects.

I previously asked this question, but have since had some advice that the suggestion to make this model polymorphic was not the right approach. I wasn't actually able to get the advice in this post working, but my question is now slightly different.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394489/rails-4-polymorphic-associations-and-concerns
```

I have a user model and an evaluation model.

User

```
has_many :given_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Evaluation
  has_many :received_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Evaluation
```

Evaluation

```
belongs_to :evaluator, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, class_name: User
  belongs_to :evaluatee, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, class_name: User
```

I'm now trying to figure out how to setup the form so that the right user gets the evaluation and to limit the which user can leave the feedback.

In the evaluation form, I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@evaluation) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :overall_score, collection: 1..10, autofocus: true, :label => "How do you rate this project experience (1 being did not meet expectations - 10 being met all expectations) ?" %>
    <%= f.input :project_score, collection: 1..10, :label => "How successful was the project (1 being did not meet expectations - 10 being met all expectations)?"   %>
    <%= f.input :continue_project?, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false, :label => "Do you intend to continue working on the project?" %>
    <%= f.input :remark, as: :text, :label => "Evaluate your project experience", :input_html => {:rows => 10}  %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my evaluations controller, I have:

```
class EvaluationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_evaluation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # before_filter :get_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /evaluations
  # GET /evaluations.json
  def index
    @evaluations = Evaluation.all
  end




  # GET /evaluations/1
  # GET /evaluations/1.json
  def show
    @received_evaluations = @user.received_evaluations
  end

  # GET /evaluations/new
  def new
    @evaluation = Evaluation.new
  end

  # GET /evaluations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /evaluations
  # POST /evaluations.json
  def create
    @evaluation = Evaluation.new(evaluation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @evaluation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @evaluation, notice: 'Evaluation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @evaluation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @evaluation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /evaluations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /evaluations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @evaluation.update(evaluation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @evaluation, notice: 'Evaluation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @evaluation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @evaluation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /evaluations/1
  # DELETE /evaluations/1.json
  def destroy
    @evaluation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to evaluations_url, notice: 'Evaluation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_evaluation
      @evaluation = Evaluation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def evaluation_params
      params[:evaluation].permit(:overall_score, :project_score, :personal_score, :remark, :work_again?, :continue_project?)
    end
end
```

Have I got the controller action for show correct? Do I need to put something in the controller to identify which user is receiving the evaluation and which is giving the evaluation. Do I need to add the :user_id to the permitted params in the evaluations controller?

How do I change the form to identify the correct user that's receiving the evaluation.

My routes are:

```
resources :evaluations

 devise_for :users, #class_name: 'FormUser',
             :controllers => {
                :registrations => "users/registrations",
                # :omniauth_callbacks => "users/authentications"
                :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks'

           }

  # get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'users/authentications#create'
  # get '/authentications/sign_out', :to => 'users/authentications#destroy' 

  # PER SOURCEY TUTORIAL ----------
  match '/users/:id/finish_signup' => 'users#finish_signup', via: [:get, :patch], :as => :finish_signup
```

**Workflow**

1. A user creates a project (owner)
2. The owner invites classmates to join the project (team mates)
3. If team mates accept by the cut off date, the users involved in the project complete the project.
4. Once complete, each user evaluates the other users involvement in the project and the project itself. To do that, each user that is involved in the project sees a button on their user page, to get a link to the evaluation form. I need to figure out how to reference the other user ids for the team mates as well as the project they worked on.

The reason why I didn't nest the evaluation route inside the user routes is that I might try (if I can figure out this part first) to separate project evaluation from team mate evaluation, in which case, I'd like to use evaluation for two purposes. I'll come back to that later. For now, the evaluation model is on a user.

Finally, I use devise gem for user authentication.

**PROBLEMS IDENTIFYING EVALUATEE**

Taking Paul's suggestion for how to identify the evaluate_id, I added this select to my evaluation form:

```
<%= f.select :evaluatee_id, User.all.map{|u| [u.formal_name]} %>
```

Paul suggested including u.id inside the [] of this line. I don't understand how all the pieces fit together in this line of code (or what map means) but I will try again to find explanations of those issues separately. I removed the u.id, because I was getting the error below (it turns out that removing it still leads to the error below):

```
Couldn't find Evaluation with 'id'=7 [WHERE "evaluations"."evaluatee_id" = ?]
```

I can see from the console that the evaluation is saving, but it is not recording the evaluatee_id.

```
Evaluation.last
  Evaluation Load (10.3ms)  SELECT  "evaluations".* FROM "evaluations"  ORDER BY "evaluations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Evaluation id: 7, evaluatee_id: 0, overall_score: nil, project_score: nil, personal_score: nil, remark: "edededededede", work_again?: nil, continue_project?: nil, created_at: "2016-06-10 02:08:44", updated_at: "2016-06-10 02:08:44", evaluator_id: 34>
```

The error message points to the show action in my evaluations controller, which has:

```
def show
    # @received_evaluations = @user.received_evaluations

    @received_evaluation = current_user.received_evaluations.find params[:id]
  end
```

Comment: Please also provide your routes (routes.rb) to understand how evaluation form is scoped - is it nested resource for user or is it independent? Is URL as commented in controller /evaluations/1 or is it /users/:id/evaluations/1?

Comment: To the same point, describe logic (workflow) of creating an evaluation. Do I open list of all users, then all projects of a single user, then create evaluation? Or do I have a list of all projects? Where exactly I press "evaluate" button to create new evaluation? So far on both new and create controller action you create new unbound evaluation, not relevant both to current user (who gives evaluation) neither to evaluated user (whom you give an evaluation)

Comment: Defining user which is giving evaluation depends on your authentication solution - how you manage users, logins, sessions. E.g. if you use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) then you have current_user [helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that polymorphic associations are the wrong approach here.

You should do this in your `#create` method to automatically record evaluations with the correct evaluator:

```
def create
  # change this: @evaluation = Evaluation.new(evaluation_params)
  # to this:
  @evaluation = current_user.given_evaluations.build(evaluation_params)

  # ... the rest is fine as-is ...      
end
```

The `current_user` comes from Devise and returns whatever user is currently logged in.

I would also make sure that `#update` does `current_user.given_evaluations.find(params[:id])`, so that you can't change evaluations you haven't written. Same for `#destroy`.

Depending on your requirements you may want to access other methods in a similar way.

Your `#show` method looks wrong to me. It should only find *one* evaluation:

```
def show
  @received_evaluation = current_user.received_evaluations.find params[:id]
end
```

Also `#index` should probably be scoped to the current user. Possibly you want to show evaluations you *gave* plus evaluations you *received*:

```
def index
  @given_evaluations = curent_user.given_evaluations
  @received_evaluations = curent_user.received_evaluations
end
```

**EDIT:** To set the `evaluatee_id`, just pass it like any other param. First, permit it to come from the front end:

```
def evaluation_params
  params[:evaluation].permit(
    :overall_score, :project_score, :personal_score,
    :remark, :work_again?, :continue_project?, :evaluatee_id)
end
```

Then add a widget to your form to let users provide it. For instance it could be a `<select>` listing all the users:

```
<%= f.select :evaluatee_id, User.all.map{|u| [u.id, u.name]} %>
```

This will generate HTML something like this:

```
<select name="evaluation[evaluatee_id]">
  <option value="1">Joe</option>
  <option value="2">Sarah</option>
  <option value="3">Fred</option>
</select>
```

In the above, `1`, `2`, and `3` are the IDs of the users you can choose to evaluate. The contents of each `<option>` are their names. The browser will submit the option value (the ID) of whichever evaluatee you choose.

Of course you should change `u.name` to whatever column/method you actually use to name users, e.g. `email` or `full_name` or whatever. Also you might want to sort and filter the list---whatever is appropriate for your app.

Also note that using a `<select>` is just one option. You could have evaluators choose the evaluatee on a prior page, and pass it through the form as a hidden field instead. Or whatever you like! The point is that as long as the front end is sending an `evaluation[evaluatee_id]`, you can save it like any other param.

Comment: Hi Paul. I tried this - thank you for the suggestion. I get an error with the evaluation controller that says: Couldn't find Evaluation with 'id'=5 [WHERE "evaluations"."evaluatee_id" = ?]
It's referencing the line in the create action that you showed me. I'm really stuck. I think something is wrong with the form. I don't know how to identify who is the recipient of the evaluation and I think the form has something to do with that problem.

Comment: I can see from the console that the evaluation is created. The evaluator_id is set to the current user id. However the evaluate_id is not set. Do you have any idea about how to set this?

Comment: You are going to need to get the evaluatee id some how.  What does that flow look like to you? I am assuming you would have another view where the user selects the person who they are evaluating and clicks submit.  Then the evaluatee_id is sent as a param to the create action as evaluatee_id.

Comment: I agree with @ruby_newbie. Possibly you could have a `<select>` dropdown within the evaluation form to choose an `evaluatee_id`.

Comment: How do you set the evaluatee id?

Comment: I added a section to my answer about setting the `evaluatee_id`.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the suggestion. I'm struggling to the figure out how to set the evaluate_id. I've shown the error messages I'm getting above. I'm just not understanding how to figure this problem out.

Comment: Hi Mel, some difficulty is understandable since there are so many parts. I added a explanation of the HTML you should see for the `<select>`. It is helpful to understand what should be happening (and what actually is happening) without worrying about the Ruby, just from a perspective of the HTML in your browser (which you can see with View Source), and the form values the browser submits (which you can see in your Inspector's Network tab). You definitely include the `u.id` so that the browser can submit it.

Comment: You can also watch each browser/server interaction in the Rails logs. Your last error was from the `#show` action. What that means is that the `#create` **worked** (before you removed `u.id`), and it redirected to user to see the evaluation it just created at `/evaluations/7`. So the browser received the redirect status and immediately asked for that URL. That second request called `#show`. . . .

Comment: . . . unfortunately `#show` only knows how to show evaluations you've **received**: `current_user.received_evaluations.find params[:id]`. But `current_user` is still the evaluator, not the evaluatee. So you could (1) change `#create` to redirect somewhere else, say to `/evaluations`, or (2) change `#show` to let you see both received and given evaluations: `@evaluation = current_user.received_evaluations.find_by(id: params[:id]) || current_user.given_evaluations.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: Note `find_by` vs `find`. The former returns `nil` if something is not found; the latter raises an exception.

Comment: Also you should definitely read about `map` and maybe do some experiments in `irb` or `rails console`. It is a little abstract but it is used in Ruby very often. Basically it lets you convert a list of things into a list of different things: `[1,2,3].map{|x| x*2}` yields `[2,4,6]`.

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth Thanks very much again for the helpful explanation.