# Rails - associations, feedback on users by users - showing feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm struggling to figure out how to set up my rails evaluation model so that users can use it to leave feedback on other users.

I outlined the key part of my problem in this post:

[Rails - feedback on specific users, how to set up the form to identify relevant users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610784/rails-feedback-on-specific-users-how-to-set-up-the-form-to-identify-relevant)

The suggestion I received from that was to set up the model as follows:

User.rb

```
has_many :given_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Evaluation
  has_many :received_evaluations, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Evaluation
```

Evaluation.rb

```
belongs_to :evaluator, foreign_key: :evaluator_id, class_name: User
  belongs_to :evaluatee, foreign_key: :evaluatee_id, class_name: User
```

Evaluation Controller

```
class EvaluationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_evaluation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # before_filter :get_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /evaluations
  # GET /evaluations.json
  def index
    # @evaluations = Evaluation.all
    @given_evaluations = current_user.given_evaluations
    @received_evaluations = current_user.received_evaluations
  end




  # GET /evaluations/1
  # GET /evaluations/1.json
  def show
    # @received_evaluations = @user.received_evaluations
    @evaluation = current_user.received_evaluations.find_by(id: params[:id]) || current_user.given_evaluations.find(params[:id])

    # @received_evaluation = current_user.received_evaluations.find params[:id]
  end

  # GET /evaluations/new
  def new
    @evaluation = Evaluation.new
  end

  # GET /evaluations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /evaluations
  # POST /evaluations.json
  def create
    # @evaluation = Evaluation.new(evaluation_params)
    @evaluation = current_user.given_evaluations.build(evaluation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @evaluation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @evaluation, notice: 'Evaluation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @evaluation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @evaluation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /evaluations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /evaluations/1.json
  def update
    current_user.given_evaluations.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @evaluation.update(evaluation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @evaluation, notice: 'Evaluation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @evaluation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @evaluation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /evaluations/1
  # DELETE /evaluations/1.json
  def destroy
    current_user.given_evaluations.find(params[:id])
    @evaluation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to evaluations_url, notice: 'Evaluation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_evaluation
      @evaluation = Evaluation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def evaluation_params
      params[:evaluation].permit(:overall_score, :project_score, :personal_score, :remark, :work_again?, :continue_project?, :evaluatee_id)
    end
end
```

Evaluation form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@evaluation) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.select :evaluatee_id, User.all.map{|u| [u.formal_name, u.id]} %>

    <%= f.input :overall_score, collection: 1..10, autofocus: true, :label => "How do you rate this project experience (1 being did not meet expectations - 10 being met all expectations) ?" %>
    <%= f.input :continue_project?, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false, :label => "Do you intend to continue working on the project?" %>
    <%= f.input :remark, as: :text, :label => "Evaluate your experience", :input_html => {:rows => 10}  %>



  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
```

Evaluation show view

```
<% @received_evaluations.each do |receval| %>
                                <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
                                        <%= receval.remark %>
                                        <%#= eval.personal_score %>
                                        <small><%= receval.created_at %></small>
                                </div>    
                            <% end %>
```

Alternative attempt at evaluation show view

```
<% @given_evaluations.each do |receval| %>
                                <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
                                        <%= receval.remark %>
                                        <%#= eval.personal_score %>
                                        <small><%= receval.created_at %></small>
                                </div>    
                            <% end %>
```

The problem I'm having now is that regardless of whether I try to show given evaluation or received evaluation in the show, I get an error message that says:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I can't figure out how to setup the model so that a user can evaluate another user. I want to show each user's received evaluation on their respective show page. i can't figure out what's going wrong. I can see from the console that a user has received evaluations as:

```
=> #<Evaluation id: 8, evaluatee_id: 34, overall_score: 4, project_score: 5, personal_score: 5, remark: "jhjkhjhjkhkjhjkhjhkhjhkj", work_again?: nil, continue_project?: nil, created_at: "2016-06-12 21:52:53", updated_at: "2016-06-12 21:52:53", evaluator_id: 34>
```

There is an entry for the user I'm working with. However, I can't find a way to show that evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most immediate problem I could see is that the instance variables: `@given_evaluations` and `@received_evaluations` are not being set in your show actions and the commented portions are using the `ActiveRecord#find` method, which would return one instance therefore the reason you couldn't loop through the evaluations.

I think a better place to show all your user's evaluation is in the `index` action, as you're doing already, you may move the current logic for the show to the index view.
To show each user's received evaluation on the `show` action, you would do:

`@evaluation = current_user.received_evaluations.find(params[:id])`

Then in your `show` view, you should have something like:

```
<div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
  <%= @evaluation.remark %>
  <%= @evaluation.personal_score %>
  <small><%= @evaluation.created_at %></small>
</div>
```